# Rewrite conditions and failure to load .php

Tags: php, apache

While my website works fine on my local environment (MAMP) when I upload the files to my server (bluehost), I run into the following issue:

I have a link with a php get variable (i.e. /xxx.php?p=bob) that invokes a javascript function  (popitup) that opens a pop-up window.

The link is structured as follows:

```
<?php echo "<a href='media_player.php?p=".$listen_now."' onclick=\"return popitup('media_player.php?p=".$listen_now."')\">"
```

The popitup function is defined as follows:

```
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=700,width=375');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

When the pop-up window opens, the page contents do not load, and I get the following message:

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

The main error log shows the following warning:

```
[Mon May 28 08:23:40 2012] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

The .htaccess file in my public_html folder does not contain any redirects or rewrites.

Any leads on how I might solve this issue are very much appreciated.

Comment: have you got any redirects in your vhost file or httpd.conf ?

Comment: afaik on bluehost he doesn't have access to either vhost or httpd.conf

Comment: to see where it comes fromm try from www root: grep -r NC .htaccess

Comment: also check cPanel >> Redirects

Comment: Make sure `media_player.php` exists add `ini_set("display_errors", 1)` to the top of it.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` warnings come from Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You have a broken rewrite rule in either:

- `.htaccess` (directory of .php file or in *any directory up the tree to the system root*)
- Virtual Host configuration
- main apache configuration

Find its location and fix it there.